# Error while installing orange2.6 cc1plus: warning: -Wstrict-prototypes’

Tags: python, ubuntu, orange

I am trying to install Orange2.6 on my ubuntu 13.10 python version 2.7.5.While running

```
python setup.py build
```

I am getting following error

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a warning not an error (and is 'expected' when compiling C++ extensions with python's distutils using gcc).
You can ignore it an let the compilation continue.